# why is my async await not working with set state?

Tags: reactjs

im using set state and i usually use async-await to set states but this time its not working. The problem specifically is on component did mount im using Axios to retrieve data. once retrieved it is supposed to call a function saving the state asynchronously. I don't think the problem is async await.

code:

```js
class Country extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    suggestions: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array),
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countryError: "",
      list: [],
      country: { value: "", country: "" },
      countryNames: [""],
      action: "",
      filterList: [],
      currentValue: "",
      tags: "",
      isInvisible: true,
    };
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
    this.changeOptions = this.changeOptions.bind(this);
  }
  //to load data upon generation.
  changeValue = async (target, value) => {
    if (target === "list") {
      await this.setState({ list: value });
    } else {
      await this.setState({ country: value });
    }

    console.log(this.state.country);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    let currentComponent = this;
    let newCountry = {};
    if (this.props.id) {
      if (this.props.id !== -1) {
        let path = "/country";

        axios
          .get("http://localhost:8080" + path + "/getById/" + this.props.id)
          .then((res) => {
            this.changeValue("country", res.data);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            let emptyItem = {
              value: "",
            };

            currentComponent.setState({ country: emptyItem }, () => {
              console.log(currentComponent.state.country);
            });
          });
      } else {
        let newRegion = {};
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:8080" + "/country/dummy")
          .then((res) => {
            this.changeValue("country", res.data);
          })
          .then()
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }

      //set for autocomplete
    }
    //get all countries
    let fromList = [];
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080" + "/country")
      .then((res) => {
        let newList = res.data;
        newList.map((e) => {
          fromList.push({ id: e.id, value: e.value });
        });
      })
      .then()
      .catch(function (error) {});
    this.changeValue("list", fromList);
  }
  async changeOptions() {
    return this.state.filterList;
  }
  //to filter list
  filterList() {
    let oldList = this.state.list;
    let newList = [];
    if (oldList[0].value) {
      oldList.map((e) => {
        if (e.value.startsWith(this.state.currentValue)) {
          newList.push(e.value);
        }
      });
    } else {
      newList = [];
    }
    this.setState({ filterList: newList });
  }
  //when a tag in a dropbox is clicked current value is the tags value
  async onClick(id) {
    await this.state.list.map((e) => {
      if (e.id == id) {
        this.setState({ currentValue: e.value });
      }
    });

    await this.setState({ isInvisible: true });
  }

  //upon input change.
  async onChange(childData) {
    await this.setState({ currentValue: childData });
    await this.filterList();
    await this.setState({ isInvisible: false });
  }

  //upon entering the input button edit or save will be completed.
  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let currentComponent = this;
    let path = "/country";
    let country = {};
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080" + path, this.state.currentValue)
      .then((res) => {
        currentComponent.setState({ countryError: res.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {});
  }
  //to remove item upon request.
  async removeItem() {
    let path = "/country";
    let description =
      "item can not be removed because it has locations inside it that need to be deleted first or item never existed.";

    let currentComponent = this;
    axios
      .delete("http://localhost:8080" + path + "/" + this.state.currentValue)
      .catch(currentComponent.setState({ countryError: description }));

    window.location.reload(false);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {" "}
          yoyoyo
          <div>
            <b>previous value:{this.state.country.value || ""}</b>
          </div>
          <label>country:</label>
          <Autocomplete
            list={this.state.filterList}
            onChangeValue={this.onChange}
          />
          <div>{this.state.countryError}</div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
        <button onClick={this.removeItem}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Exporting the component
export default Country;
```

Comment: I don't see any question here

Comment: And, please, format the code!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is because when axios is calling it will send fromList to changeValue method when axios gets the response won't call changeValue again
you need to send formList to changeValue in then of axios call
something like this:

```
 let fromList = []
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8080' + '/country')
      .then(res => {
        let newList = res.data;
        newList.map(e => {
          fromList.push({ id: e.id, value: e.value });
        });
        this.changeValue('list', fromList);
      })
      .then()
      .catch(function (error) {});
```